# How can I get qemu's Ctrl+Alt keys working in -curses mode?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, openbsd

So here's the situation; I currently have qemu installed on an OpenBSD 5.3 snapshot.  This is a console setup so I have to either run with -curses or -nographic.  The problem here is that I'm having difficulties getting to the qemu monitor when running in -curses mode.  The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys don't seem to work at all.  This means I have to get dirty and kill the qemu process from another console/ssh session, as the current console essentially becomes locked.  Unfortunately -nographic mode isn't an option as the OS is not set up to use serial for I/O.

All I can think of right now is maybe looking into a way of converting a spare console into a dedicated qemu monitor, but I haven't made much progress on that angle.  Google has not been very helpful thus far, but maybe I just didn't think up a cute enough search to dig through the noise.

The main question here is: How do I get the qemu keys working in -curses?

If that's not possible: How do I set up a dedicated qemu monitor on a spare console?

Answer (score 10):

When running with `-curses`, you use just <kbd>Alt</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>, so <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> should take you to the monitor.

If your terminal is deficient and does not send <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> correctly, you can type <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>2</kbd>.